# Statement analysis of two different algorithms

Tags: java, time-complexity

I have recently made a bike trip analyzer where you enter your distance travelled and average speed from that trip, and it calculates your time, ranks your current speed with your minimum speed, maximum speed and average speed of all the speeds you have entered to date, and then charts your progress (last 10 trips) by speed, distance, and time. Things have been going according to plan, except for when I had to delete records (incorrect ones at that), and ran the program as normal (the numbering was all screwed up due to what the database was doing with the index). I added a function to help alleviate some of that, but it didn't entirely take care of the problem. (It wouldn't display exactly 10 records because some record numbers were missing on the intervals specified.) So now, I am improving it, and found two ways to do so.

I have found a simple recursive way to do it, and a corresponding iterative way to do it.

---

The recursive way:

```
private int calculateOffset(int min, int max)
{
    int actualTripNumber = 0, expectedTripNumber = 0, totalOffset = 0;
    try
    {
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT TripNumber FROM BikeTripRecords WHERE TripNumber > " + 
            ((max == 0) ? String.format("(SELECT max(TripNumber) FROM BikeTripRecords) - %d", maxShowableRecords) : 
                String.format("%d AND TripNumber < %d", min, max))
            );
        //we could set expectedTripNumber = min + 1 (and then offset = min + 1), but that would cost one instruction
        while (resultSet.next())
        {
            actualTripNumber = resultSet.getInt(1);     //get the actualTripNumber
            totalOffset += ((expectedTripNumber > 0) ? actualTripNumber - expectedTripNumber : actualTripNumber - (min + 1));   //calculate the offset
            expectedTripNumber = actualTripNumber + 1;  //we expect the next actualTripNumber to be one more than the current one
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return -1;  //You KNOW something went wrong with a negative return value; this could be replaced by System.exit(1), however
    }

    //conditional tail recursion; this should end with the last recursive call to return 0
    if (totalOffset > 0)
    {
        //if this function was called from the outside 
        if (max == 0)
        {
            //we assign to max the first number from the resultSet
            int newMax = resultSet.getInt(1);
            totalOffset += calculateOffset(newMax - totalOffset, newMax);
        }
        else
        {
            totalOffset += calculateOffset(min - totalOffset, min);
        }
    }
    return totalOffset;
}
```

The iterative way:

```
private int calculateOffset()
{
    //This version of calculateOffset() will be ITERATIVE, not recursive (and will use a helper function)
    int totalOffset = 0, intervalOffset = 1000; //giving intervalOffset a garbage value (so that we could use it in the while loop)
    int minimum = 0, maximum = 0;
    //this is the first calculation; we obtain the max(TripNumber) from BikeTripRecords (this method will only be called ONCE)
    try
    {
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT max(TripNumber) FROM BikeTripRecords");
        resultSet.next();
        maximum = resultSet.getInt(1);  //fetching maximum
        minimum = maximum - maxShowableRecords;     //while we are at it, we might as well assign minimum a value here, too...
        }
    catch (SQLException exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return -1;  // You know something went wrong when the return value is negative!!
    }
    //we simply add to totalOffset the return value of our helper function (the offset of the intervals specified) while it doesn't return 0
    while (intervalOffset > 0)
    {
        intervalOffset = getIntervalOffset(minimum, maximum);   //get the intervalOffset
        totalOffset += intervalOffset;      //add it to the totalOffset
        //recalculate maximum, minimum
        maximum = minimum;
        minimum -= intervalOffset;
    }
    return totalOffset;
}

//helper function
private int getIntervalOffset (int min, int max)
{
    int offset = 0; //the value of this variable will be the return value (if everything goes according to plan)
    int actualTripNumber = 0, expectedTripNumber = 0;
    try
    {
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(String.format("SELECT TripNumber FROM BikeTripRecords WHERE TripNumber > %d AND TripNumber <= %d", min, max));
        //computing the offset of the interval
        while (resultSet.next())
        {
            actualTripNumber = resultSet.getInt(1);     //getting the actualTripNumber
            //the only offset there should be the first time around should be the difference between the actualTripNumber and one more than the min
            //otherwise, the offset should be the difference between the actualTripNumber and the expectedTripNumber
            offset += ((expectedTripNumber > 0) ? actualTripNumber - expectedTripNumber : actualTripNumber - (min + 1));    
            expectedTripNumber = actualTripNumber + 1;  //the expectedTripNumber should be one more than the actualTripNumber
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return -1;  // How you KNOW something went wrong....
    }
    return offset;
}
```

Both code snippets examine k intervals (k is positive integer). What I am stumped on is the calculation of the algorithmic complexity of each approach. The critical section of both ways is exactly the same: a while loop that executes exactly 10-m times (with m being the calculated number of missing records in the interval being examined). Here, we can definitely say that m is bounded above by 10. What I came up with for both methods is a complexity that is linear with respect to k and sum(mj, j between 1 and k), namely 32k-(2+3 sum (mj, j between 1 and k-1)) for the recursive way and 4+31k-3 sum (mj, j between 1 and k-1). (Here, mj reads "m sub j".) Would the complexity of both algorithms be amortized or would it be O(max{k, sum(mj, j between 1 and k-1)})?

Comment: I have tested both algorithms by hand by simulating the Derby database with a table that has TripNumber automatically generated as index, and multiple records deleted (across the multiple intervals where we are interested).

Comment: You're dealing with 10 records and you're worried about asymptotic complexity?

Comment: On a side note, iterative does not have the method call overhead (but this is a very minor optimization and equals 4 lines of assembly each call)

Comment: I guess I should have stated the pseudocode that is what I am trying to accomplish here. The problem is thus: when I try to fetch the last 10 records, not exactly 10 records are fetched. I could fetch them all, in reverse order, and only care about the "first" 10, but that would run me into two problems. The first would be the order in which they are displayed (an invitation to shoot myself in the foot). The second is the values of the domain axis (I don't want record skips. Sidestepping this, I have numbered all the records according to trip count and tried the above method.

Comment: It involves calculating all the `totalOffset` (the amount of missing records), and then saying something like `resultSet = statement.executeQuery(String.format("SELECT * FROM BikeTripRecords WHERE TripNumber > (SELECT max(TripNumber) FROM BikeTripRecords)-%d",totalOffset));`. This way, exactly 10 records are fetched, and the numbering of the domain axis does not suffer.

Comment: Basically, it involves moving between intervals until we run into exactly 10 actual records (the amount of records fetched on the first run is exactly `10-offset`, the second run will return a maximum of  `offset` amount of records).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to, for the recursive method, add the following code at the beginning of the try block:

```
if (max == 0)
{
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT max(TripNumber) FROM BikeTripRecords");
    resultSet.next();
    min = resultSet.getInt(1);
}
```

which may be bad code practice because

- I have to say "SELECT max(TripNumber) FROM BikeTripRecords" multiple times
- `min` and `max` are unused the first time around!!

Seeing all this, I have simply decided to go with the iterative method, as it is the path of lesser resistance here.

Also, I have just received my "AHA!" moment: the `resultSet.next()` will return true exactly 10 times for both methods from start to completion, and so the critical section of both methods have complexity of 30. Thus, both methods are amortized. Despite this, I still went with the iterative method, as it was better practice.

Answer (score 1):

Why not save yourself the headache and just get the 10 most recent results?

Since you're using derby, you can limit your results with:

```
statement.setMaxRows(10);
```

Then, assuming your `TripNumber` column is an auto incremented id, you can just order the results:

```
SELECT TripNumber FROM BikeTripRecords 
ORDER BY TripNumber DESC
```

Comment: My msitake. Should have been `DESC`. Also included how to `LIMIT` in derby.

Comment: This is doable, but quoting myself, I would have to worry about both the display order and the values of the domain axis (I don't want record skips.) I would have to call `resultSet.afterLast();` and then the condition in the while loop will be `resultSet.previous()`. Also, I want to be able to display the record number as the value in the domain axis (clearly, an auto-generated ID is NOT reliable for this purpose). To do this, I would have to fetch the recordCount somehow, and subtract `resultSet.getRow()` from recordCount in the loop. But then again, I am already fetching the recordCount.

Comment: @MikeWarren Personally, I think iterating in reverse is going to be more comprehensible and succinct than any other option.